# Is the binding of two implementations to one interface possible the ioc way in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**update see below**

In the laravel documentation I found a good description of binding one implementation to its interface which is good for unit testing purposes. But say I want to bind two implementations which share the same interface, is that possible too?

I am trying specificially to inject a different ValidationServices into the construct method of `LoginController` and `RegisterController`. Both construct methods look like this

```
public function __construct(ValidationServiceInterface $validation) {
        $this->validation = $validation;
    }
```

Now, is there a way to tell the app to instantiate say `LoginUserValidationService` in the one case and instantiate `RegisterUserValidationService` in the other? Any clues and hints are welcome.

**Update**
One way to solve this binding problem lies in php's capability to extend interfaces. So it is possible to introduce two interfaces (`LoginUserValidationServiceInterface`and `RegisterUserValidationServiceInterface`) which both extend `ValidationServiceInterface`. The first then is implemented by `LoginUserValidationService` which is needed in `LoginController` and the second by `RegisteUserValidationService` which is needed in `RegistrationController`.

The benefit of this solution is that laravel's ioc binding can still be used. The `ValidationServiceProvider` class is a good location to register the bindings:

```
class ValidationServiceProvider extends Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {
    public function register(){
        $this->app->bind(
            'LoginUserValidationServiceInterface',
            'LoginUserValidationService'
        );
        $this->app->bind(
            'RegisterUserValidationServiceInterface',
            'RegisterUserValidationService'
        );

    }
}
```

So the usability of the ioc container is kept. Its price is the introduction of two interfaces though. Probably an overkill, but I choose to go that way for now ...

Comment: There shouldn't really be a need for an interface for a ValidationService.  What I do is have my ValidationServer be an abstract class which only processes the Validation using the Laravel Validator.  The rules and different situations you validate on should be placed in UserValidator, which would extend the abstract class ValidationService.  Then you can call something like `$userValidator->validateForRegistration($user);` or `$userValidator->validateForLogin($user);`.  Then if you have other models, other than users, you can create a new class which would again extend the abstract one.

Comment: My setting looks pretty much the same and your solution is legitimate. The difference between the way you managed the problem and my approach seems that you delegated the responsibility of validation to two methods of your UserValidator class. I am looking to get it working with two classes (`LoginUserValidationService` and `RegisterUserValidationService`) which both implement the same interface and extend the same abstract class (it is also called `ValidationService`). Hmm. Probably I will go your way too. So thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However both `LoginUserValidationService` and `RegisterUserValidationService` should implements `ValidationServiceInterface`.

```
class LoginUserValidationService implements ValidationServiceInterface
{
    //..
}
```

then you can do such:

```
$controller = new LoginController(new LoginUserValidationService);
```

Comment: That could do the trick i suppose. But still I am wondering if there isn't a way to let laravel's ioc capability resolve the two different classes as implementations of the `ValidationServiceInterface`. But thanks for the suggestion.